# Cannot authenticate Azure service

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, botframework

I am creating a Microsoft Teams Bot and have two similar projects. I have two resources in Azure: app service and Azure bot. I believe app service is responsible for running my bot in Azure.

Project A: So: I created new client secret for the Azure bot. Now my bot (already deployed) doesn't work, in the logs I can see an error about wrong client secret. But where do I need to put it? I updated the Authentication Service provider (Test connection gives the Token, so secret value is correct) in Azure bot.

Comment: Azure Bot secrets are usually found in the key vault. If the keys have changed, you might also need to update the `appsettings.json` file in your bot's code and redeploy it.

Comment: @AP01 Thanks! Acutually publishing the app with updated appsettings.json was the resolution!

Comment: @Morales1235 Could you please port your resolution steps as answer so that it could be helpful for other community members

Answer (score 0):

The resolution was to publish application with updated values in appsettings.json. Probably even the local Bot Emulator uses authentication settings from Azure.

Comment: When running the bot locally, if you specify an id and password in appsettings, you need to also specify it in the pop-up when connecting to the bot in emulator.